# VBA - Printing in descending order

Tags: vba, ms-office

I'm trying to print a single document with `control number`, there will be more than 3,000 copies of the hard copy of the document, and the whole page will be cut into two, both sides should have the control number.

I'm using the below macros to automatically generate the control number and print it, I just run this macro, specify the number of copies then done; The format of the control number is `00000`.

```
' This macro will create a dual control number for a single document and automatically print it.
'
Sub AutoNew()
'
' AutoNew Macro
'
'
Dim Message As String, Title As String, Default As String, NumCopies As Long, SavedFile As String
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range

' Set prompt.
Message = "How many copies do you want to print?"
' Set title.
Title = "Printing Setup, how many copies do you want to print?"
' Set default number to print.
Default = "1"
' Display message, title, and default value.
NumCopies = Val(InputBox(Message, Title, Default))

' Set default control number
SerialNumber = 1
SavedFile = "D:\saved_control_number.txt"

' Read the saved file for the next counter of control number or serial number.
' If file doesn't exist, then we start from control number or serial number as 1.
' file name is "saved_control_number.txt" and should be on drive D.
If FileThere(SavedFile) Then
    SerialNumber = System.PrivateProfileString("D:\saved_control_number.txt", "MacroSettings", "SerialNumber")
End If

Set Rng1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SerialNumber").Range
Set Rng2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SerialNumber2").Range
Counter = 0
' Reset or empty the text of Bookmark SerialNumber & SerialNumber2
Rng1.text = ""
Rng2.text = ""

While Counter < NumCopies
    Rng1.Delete
    Rng1.text = Format(SerialNumber, "00000")
    Rng2.Delete
    Rng2.text = Format(SerialNumber, "00000")
    ' This should be print in descending order.
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut
    SerialNumber = SerialNumber + 1
    Counter = Counter + 1
Wend

'Save the next number back to the Settings.txt file ready for the next use.
System.PrivateProfileString("D:\saved_control_number.txt", "MacroSettings", "SerialNumber") = SerialNumber

'Recreate the bookmark ready for the next use.
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .Add Name:="SerialNumber", Range:=Rng1
    .Add Name:="SerialNumber2", Range:=Rng2
End With

ActiveDocument.Save

End Sub

' Function to check if file saved_control_number.txt exist.
Function FileThere(FileName As String) As Boolean
     FileThere = (Dir(FileName) > "")
End Function
```

BUT, I'm still having a hard time sorting the hard copy.

**First**, let's say I want to print `50 copies` then the first print should be `00050`, and the last printed copy should be `00001`. I want it to print in descending order.

**Second**, for some reason, the print starts at `12` I don't know if the problem is in the logic of the code or in the printer. The output will be `00012`, `00011`, `00001`, `00002`, `00003`, `00004`, `...`.

I'm thinking maybe I can put the control number in the array then sort it in descending order and print, but I'd like to know your thoughts first for the solution especially for the second issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off background printing, via:

```
ActiveDocument.PrintOut Background:=False
```

Comment: Please provide more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your control number into an array then sort it into descending order and print, but that would be overkill and will produce too much task.

I suggest starting the printing in descending order with the following logic.

```
...
LastControlNumber = 1

' Get the last control number to print.
If SerialNumber > 1 Then
    SerialNumber = (SerialNumber + NumCopies) - 1 ' we will start the serial number from the last one.
    LastControlNumber = SerialNumber
End If

While Counter < NumCopies
    Rng1.Delete
    Rng1.text = Format(SerialNumber, "00000")
    Rng2.Delete
    Rng2.text = Format(SerialNumber, "00000")
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut ' print
    SerialNumber = SerialNumber - 1 ' subtract instead of addition to print in descending order.
    Counter = Counter + 1
Wend

' Put back the last control number in the document so you don't get confused.
SerialNumber = LastControlNumber
Rng1.Delete
Rng1.text = Format(SerialNumber, "00000")
Rng2.Delete
Rng2.text = Format(SerialNumber, "00000")

'Save the next number back to the saved_control_number.txt file ready for the next use.
System.PrivateProfileString("D:\saved_control_number.txt", "MacroSettings", "SerialNumber") = SerialNumber + 1 ' + 1 because we want to print the next control number next time.
...
```

Remove your `While`-`Wend` and replace it with the above code.

The second problem is probably related to the buffer of your printer. I suggest delaying the printout in your code for at least one to two seconds, then see if it prints correctly.